# Remove element by Key

Tags: filtering, associations

I'm trying to remove the key and respective value from an association where the key starts with an underscore.

So some association:

```
asso = <|"key1"->{}, "key2"->"string", "_key3"->3, 
    "_key4"-><|"key5">"otherString","_key6"->"otherOtherString"|>
|>
```

should become just:

```
<|"key1"->{},"key2"->"string"|>
```

Note everything in the value for `_key4` is removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Also

```
KeySelect[StringStartsQ[Except @ "_"]][asso]
```

> <|"key1" -> {}, "key2" -> "string"|>

Comment: That works too, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
asso // KeyDrop@Select[Keys[asso], StringStartsQ["_"]]
```

Comment: My god that is complicated.

Comment: You're spot on with that code, thank you.